# C++ confusion about one definition rule

Tags: c++, undefined-behavior, one-definition-rule

I was reading about [**One Definition Rule**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition). It says that:

> if one .cpp file defines **struct S { int x; };** and the other .cpp file
> defines **struct S { int y; };**, the behavior of the program that links
> them together is undefined. This is usually resolved with unnamed
> namespaces.

I don't understand why & how it is undefined? Will someone explain me the actual reason behind this? How it is resolved with unnamed namespaces?

Comment: You're declaring the same struct two different ways, so that the two different parts of the code see it differently. Admittedly, changing just the names but keeping the types the same will probably work on most C++ compilers today, but the spec guarentees nothing.

Comment: This example is a violation of the requirement that two types with external linkage and the same name are defined using the same sequence of tokens (i.e., whitespace differences are allowed, but type aliases such as typedefs are not) as well as that lookup finds the same entities when the tokens are resolved.  That bit about the same token sequence is found in the first bullet of the bulletted list of rules in the page you linked to.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's just as it says. You defined the same class `S` twice, with different definitions. The makers of the language have declared that *you shall not do this*. The reason is that allowing it would be clearly nonsensical, and result in breaking compatibility across your translation units. Which definition is the "right" one? Which should your compiler use?

An unnamed namespace results in the two definitions actually defining *different* classes `S`, which are properly named something akin to `my-anonymous-namespace-1::S` and `my-anonymous-namespace-2::S`, though you can never refer to them like that because the namespaces are, well, anonymous.

Comment: Thanks. It makes sense