# struct with same name but different member in C++

Tags: c++, c++11, undefined-behavior, one-definition-rule

As per book *The C++ Programming Language* (Bjarne Stroustrup), in section 15.2.3 (The One definition rule) page no 425, I write program as below :

file1.cpp

```
struct S2 { int a; char b; };
```

file2.cpp

```
struct S2 { int a; char bb; };
int main(){ return 0;}
```

To compile I tried below command.

```
g++ -std=c++11 file1.cpp file2.cpp
```

and

```
clang++ -std=c++11 file1.cpp file2.cpp
```

Both these command producing executable with out any error or warning. But as per book this example should give error.

Comment: I'm not sure if this is a violation of the *one definition rule* (ODR) or not.  However, if it is, the compiler is *not* required to give an error - it just means that the programmer has made a mistake.

Comment: @MartinBonner: yes this is clear violation of ODR. you are right. Compiler isn't required to give an error

Comment: Please don't insert links to commercial sites.

Comment: @YvesDaoust. Okay Understood.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

[***One Definition Rule***](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/definition) says that:

> if one .cpp file defines `struct S { int x; };` and the other .cpp
>   file defines `struct S { int y; };`, the behavior of the program that
>   links them together is **undefined**.

So, your program invokes undefined behaviour (UB). So, compiler isn't required to give diagnosis for this.

If you want know the reason behind it then read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32700125/c-confusion-about-one-definition-rule).

Hope it helps. :)