# ODR violation (Weak symbol is overridden by weak symbol)

Tags: c++, gcc, linker, static-linking

There is following directory structure:

```
├── A
│   ├── A.cpp
│   ├── A.hpp
│   ├── A.o
│   └── Evil.hpp
├── B
│   ├── B.cpp
│   ├── B.hpp
│   ├── B.o
│   └── Evil.hpp
├── main.cpp
└── main.o
```

A.hpp:

```
#pragma once
#include "Evil.hpp"

struct A {
A();
~A();

Evil mid;
};
```

A.cpp:

```
#include "A.hpp"

A::A() {
    printf("OuterClass A ctor\n");
}

A::~A() {
    printf("OuterClass A dtor\n");
}
```

Evil.hpp: (from A/)

```
#pragma once
#include <cstdio>

struct Evil {
    Evil() {
        printf("Evil A ctor\n");
    }
};
```

B.hpp:

```
#pragma once
#include "Evil.hpp"

struct B {
B();
~B();

Evil mid;
};
```

B.cpp:

```
#include "B.hpp"

B::B() {
    printf("OuterClass B ctor\n");
}

B::~B() {
    printf("OuterClass B dtor\n");
}
```

Evil.hpp:

```
#pragma once
#include <cstdio>

struct Evil {
Evil() {
    printf("Evil B ctor\n");
}
};
```

main.cpp

```
#include "A/A.hpp"

int main(){
A a;
return 0;
}
```

When compiled with commands:

```
g++ -c A.cpp
g++ -c B.cpp
g++ -c main.cpp
g++ main.o A.o B.o -o out
```

The output is:

```
Evil A ctor
OuterClass A ctor
OuterClass A dtor
```

But when order of linking is changed:

```
g++ main.o B.o A.o -o out
```

The output is (and possible crash when Evil.hpp definition is different):

```
Evil B ctor
OuterClass A ctor
OuterClass A dtor
```

I know that linking order matters but why in that case symbols are not defined? As I understand Evil.hpp is fully defined in hpp file hence is 'inlined' and definitions are present in all included cpp. The interesting part is that nm outputs in both A.o and B.o both symbols as weak:

```
0000000000000000 W _ZN4EvilC1Ev
0000000000000000 W _ZN4EvilC2Ev
0000000000000000 n _ZN4EvilC5Ev
```

So the question here I believe is: why weak symbol from A.o is overriden by other weak symbol from B.o? I thought that weak symbol can be overridden only by strong symbol?
Compiled on:

> g++ (Ubuntu 10.3.0-1ubuntu1) 10.3.0

Comment: *"So the question here I believe is: why weak symbol from A.o is overriden by other weak symbol from B.o?"* -- From this I understand that you are looking for the linking convention that dictates this result, not the C++ reason this result is allowed. Is that your intent? (The latter is covered by [confusion about one definition rule](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32700125/), but that does not address technicalities of linking.)

Comment: Yes, I'm more interested in linking convention, particularly why weak symbol that supposed to be only allowed to be overriden by a strong one is in this case overriden.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what different output/bahviour you expect. Let's assume that you have only one `Evil.hpp` in the same directory of `main.cpp` and in both `A` and `B` an `#include "../Evil.hpp"` then the output you get for `nm` is the same. The c++ specification dictates that `Evil` must have the same implementation (no matter if it originates from two files or from one) otherwise static linking to a binary build on a different machine would not work. ...

Comment: ... . So the linker assumes that the `W` of `Evil` in all compilation units is the same, and chooses one of them (which might be the first one). So why should that be ODR violation?